# Error when trying to duplicate rows in DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an existing datatable called `_longDataTable` containing data. Now, I want to duplicate each row and in each duplicate of the row, I want to set only the value in the `SheetCode` column according to a value from a different datatable called `values`, see code below. For example, the `values` datatable contains 1, 2 and 3, then I want each row of `_longDataTable` to be duplicated three times and in each of the duplicated rows, I want the `Sheet Code` column to have values 1, 2 and 3 respectively. My code now looks like below:

```
foreach (DataRow sheets in _longDataTable.Rows)
{
   for(int k = 0; k < number_of_sheets; k++)
   {
      var newRowSheets = _longDataTable.NewRow();
      newRowSheets.ItemArray = sheets.ItemArray;

      newRowSheets["SheetCode"] = values.Rows[k]["Sheet Code"];

      //add edited row to long datatable
      _longDataTable.Rows.Add(newRowSheets);
   }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
```

Does anyone know where this error comes from and how to solve my problem?

Comment: The easiest way is `foreach (DataRow sheets in _longDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList())`. You can't add new row while using `DataTable` enumerator.

Comment: You are having the error as the `_longDataTable` is **immutable** in `foreach` for more info go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). So, use an alternate approach like a temp/secondary storage

Comment: @Tetsuya do you have an idea why I'm getting the: "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. " error when using your approach?

Answer (score 0):

you get enumeration error because you are iterating through a collection which is changing in the loop(new rows added to it),

as you said in the comment, you get out of memory exception because you are iterating on the _longDataTable, then you add rows to it, the iteration never reach to end and you will get out of memory exception.

I assume this can help you:

```
            //assume _longDataTable has two columns : column1 and SheetCode
        var _longDataTable = new DataTable();
        var duplicatedData = new DataTable();

        duplicatedData.Columns.Add("Column1");
        duplicatedData.Columns.Add("SheetCode");

        foreach (DataRow sheets in _longDataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < number_of_sheets; k++)
            {
                var newRowSheets = duplicatedData.NewRow();
                newRowSheets.ItemArray = sheets.ItemArray;

                newRowSheets["SheetCode"] = values.Rows[k]["Sheet Code"];
                newRowSheets["Column1"] = "anything";

                //add edited row to long datatable
                duplicatedData.Rows.Add(newRowSheets);
            }
        }

        _longDataTable.Merge(duplicatedData);
```

do not modify _longDataTable, add rows to the temp table (with the same schema) and after the iteration merge two data tables.

Comment: Do you also know how to deal with the case that _longDataTable has more than two columns?

Comment: you just need to add as many  duplicatedData.Columns.Add("Your column name");  as you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives my the following error: "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. "

Comment: Its a pseudo code, you should write your own customized code for it. you cant just copy and paste and expect it to run.